Hydropneumatic issue
Could you help me by giving me examples of a task that was left to me.
Design a hydropneumatic system for the actuation of transversal and longitudinal movement, applicable to a  three-step precision manufacturing process.
Some examples could be injection, extrusion, blowing plastics or feeding parts for manufacturing.
But I need to know exactly one piece or process.
Please and thank you.

This sounds like homework so you'll need to show your own effort such as sketches of the mechanical layout and fluid schematics. Then you'll get plenty of response. We won't do  your project for you.

"giving me examples of a task that was left to me" "Some examples could be injection, extrusion, blowing plastics or feeding parts for manufacturing"- If you know that, why ask us for it? What did an attempt to research any of these processes yield about "exactly one piece or process"?
